# systemd /run directories going away and not being recreated

Tags: systemd

I organized my socket files into `/run/mydir/x.socket`, `/run/mnydir/y.socket`, etc. On reboot, `/run/mydir` is not recreated so these jobs do not start. Creating and setting the correct permissions and starting the services works fine.

I'd rather not put these socket files back in `/tmp` so what's the right way to handle this? My systemd files do have these lines:

```
RuntimeDirectory=/run/mydir
RuntimeDirectoryPreserve=restart
```

But they don't seem to do anything.

Comment: The `RuntimeDirectory` parameter is relative to `/run`. Set the value to just `mydir`. You can also set up specific config in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/mydir.conf`.